# Animated SVG progress bar with steps

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have progress bar with steps like in this example:
http://jsbin.com/yuyojepuda/edit?html,css,js,output , but I need to animate it to fill the line from 0 to 100%.

```css
.completed {
      stroke: #FBAA33;
      fill: #FBAA33;
    }
    
    .not-complete {
      stroke: #555e6c;
      fill: #555e6c;
    }
```

```html
        <svg width="1000" height="1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
      <defs>
        <g id="step">
          <line x1="10" y1="50" x2="90" y2="50" style="stroke:#555e6c; stroke-width:10; stroke-linecap:round"/>
          <circle cx="90" cy="50" r="20" style="fill:#555e6c; stroke-width:0;" />
          <line x1="10" y1="50" x2="90" y2="50" style="stroke:inherit; stroke-width:5; stroke-linecap:round" z-index="100"/>
          <circle cx="90" cy="50" r="17" style="fill:inherit; stroke-width:0;" />
        </g>
      </defs>  
      <use transform="translate(320 0)" class="not-complete" xlink:href="#step" />
      <use transform="translate(240 0)" class="completed" xlink:href="#step" />
      <use transform="translate(160 0)" class="completed" xlink:href="#step" />
      <use transform="translate(80 0)" class="completed" xlink:href="#step" />
      <use transform="translate(0 0)" class="completed" xlink:href="#step" />
      <line x1="10" y1="50" x2="400" y2="50" style="stroke:#FBAA33; stroke-width:5; stroke-linecap:round" z-index="100"/>
    </svg>
```

I found a lot of examples, like this: http://jsbin.com/yuyojepuda/2/edit?html,css,js,output , but I can't apply it on my code.

One more question. Is it possible instead these circles to put some DIVs or something else where I can put some (background-)image?